# The energy encapsulated in a dielectric region

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy

An inner conductor cylindrical shell has total charge of +Q, and the outer conductor cylindrical shell has -Q. I have to find the energy encapsulated in the dielectric region ( the region between the two conductors). When my teacher solved this problem he used simply the formula; $$energy=ε/2 \int_v^\ E^2  dv $$

the limits of the volumetric integral are radius of the cylinders. Now my questions is, are not we supposed to use this formula only in the case that we are integrating on the whole space in which we are neglecting some other terms? But it was not mentioned that the volume is infinite.

Comment: The last two sentences of your question are hard to follow: Which other terms? What is the relation of the last sentence to the rest of the question. The "but" suggests an opposition to something, but to what? please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

This is a capacitor.
The is no electric field inside the inner conductor and outside the outer conductor so your integral will be zero in these regions.
All you need is to do the integration between the inner and outer conductor.

Answer (score 0):

The energy stored in the electric field in an infinitesimal volume $dV = dxdydz $ centered around the point $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ is given by $dU(\vec{r}) =\frac{\epsilon}{2}E(\vec{r})^{2}*dV $ where $\epsilon$ is the permittivity of space at $\vec{r}$ ($\epsilon = \epsilon_{0}$ if no dielectric is present at $\vec{r}$ ). To get the energy stored in some volume $\Omega$, you simply integrate the above $$ U = \int_\Omega \frac{\epsilon}{2}E(\vec{r})^{2}dV $$ In your case the volume containing the dielectric lies between the two shells, so that's the region you integrate over. Also in your question, due to the given charge configurations, the electric field inside the inner shell and the field outside the outer shell would be zero so integrating over all of space would be identical to the above integral.